# Get the location and id of asset volumne

Tags: templating

Is it possible to get the location (/media) and id (1) of an asset volume from within a Craft template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is. You can get the volume as you want, for example

```twig
{% set volume = craft.app.getVolumes().getVolumeByHandle('images') %}
```

Of if you have an asset

```twig
{% set asset = craft.assetFieldHandly.one() %}
{% set volume = asset.getVolume() %}
```

And output the information

```twig
{{ volume.path }}
{{ volume.id }}
```

if `{{ volume.path }}` contains an alias you can do `{{ alias(volume.path) }}` to display the resolved path